# How to Transition UWP Navigation View Pane Like Split View Pane

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, navigation

I recently started using the new NavigationView that comes with the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK. Previously, I was using the SplitView control. One of the most noticeable missing features for me was pane open and close animation and/or transition. I am pretty sure that there is a way to do it, but I couldn't find anything at all online. Here is a basic equivalent of my current code:

```
<NavigationView Name="MainNavigationView">
    <NavigationView.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Left"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </NavigationView.Transitions>

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="HomeView" Icon="Home" Content="Home Page"/>
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Conversion Categories"/>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="WordProcessingFileTypesView" Icon="AlignLeft" Content="Word Processing"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
</NavigationView>
```

I simplified it to make it as easy to set up as possible. To reiterate, the problem I am trying to solve is getting an open and close animation for the `NavigationView.MenuItems` pane when the hamburger menu button is toggled. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#navigationview-display-modes

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I was previously aware of that article; however, it does not fix my issue as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem I am trying to solve is getting an open and close animation for the NavigationView.MenuItems pane when the hamburger menu button is toggled.

If you edit the `NavigationView`'s default template, you will find that it actually still has a `SplitView` in its `ControlTemplate`. So, your requirement still is how to add animations for `SplitView`'s pane when it's opened/closed.

Then, you could edit `SplitView`'s template and change the specific `VisualTransition` to meet your requirement.

After that, you could apply the custom `SplitView`'s style to the `SplitView` control which is contained in `NavigationView`'s default template.

```xml
<Style x:Key="SplitViewStyle1" TargetType="SplitView">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="SplitView">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneGridLength, FallbackValue=0, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition2" Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisplayModeStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Closed" To="OpenOverlayLeft">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HCPaneBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.NegativeOpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.35" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.35" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LightDismissLayer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LightDismissLayer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0"/>
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.35" Value="1.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    ......
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="PaneRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding PaneBackground}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
                            <Grid.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="PaneClipRectangle">
                                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneClipRectangleTransform"/>
                                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                </RectangleGeometry>
                            </Grid.Clip>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneTransform"/>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Border Child="{TemplateBinding Pane}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HCPaneBorder" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="1" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Border Child="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="LightDismissLayer" Fill="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```xml
<Style x:Key="NavigationViewStyle1" TargetType="NavigationView">
        ......
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationView">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                        ......
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonSize}" Canvas.ZIndex="100">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid x:Name="TogglePaneTopPadding"/>
                            <Button x:Name="TogglePaneButton" AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation" Grid.Row="1" Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <SplitView x:Name="RootSplitView" DisplayMode="Overlay" Style="{StaticResource SplitViewStyle1}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CompactPaneLength="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}" IsTabStop="False" IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenPaneLength="{TemplateBinding OpenPaneLength}" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground}">
                            <SplitView.Pane>
                                <Grid x:Name="PaneContentGrid">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="PaneContentGridToggleButtonRow" Height="56"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPaneTopPadding"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="AutoSuggestArea" Height="40" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding AutoSuggestBox}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="12,0,12,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <Button x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestButton" Content="&#xE11A;" MinHeight="40" Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <NavigationViewList x:Name="MenuItemsHost" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MenuItemsSource}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="3" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="FooterContentBorder" Child="{TemplateBinding PaneFooter}" Grid.Row="4"/>
                                    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SettingsNavPaneItem" Grid.Row="5">
                                        <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
                                        </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                                    </NavigationViewItem>
                                </Grid>
                            </SplitView.Pane>
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" MinHeight="48" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </SplitView>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```